# chrome extension reload on file change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been searching for-ever!
I`m working on windows and ubuntu, mostly on windows.
I searched the web for lot's of external libraries such as opn, open etc' but none of these could open this URL:

chrome://extensions

I want to put in the the script tag inside package.json
or in my build.js script

so that every time after I run "npm run build"
the chrome://extensions page will reload and also the additional page I`m testing on.

I once was able to do that exactly, but I lost that solution.

part of the problem is that I can't open chrome:
the ':' symbol is not recognized in the OS as valid protocol or something and it is escaped from chrome address bar if executed from command line.

I have tried many solutions.

I am not happy with the different resolutions proposed in the research I've made in Stack.O.
reloader as an extension is out of the question I want a script.

your kind help.

Assaf.

Comment: hot-reload.js is no good either, very buggy and crashes after couple of reloads

Comment: Use nativeMessaging API + chrome.runtime.reload(). See the documentation for both.

Comment: what about testing for ie?

Comment: I don't like the idea of running code to test your software inside of your code's software...so I`m not happy with nativeMessaging.
Unless there's an implementation I've missed.
I'll try giving it a 2nd look

Answer (score -1):

#### [Clerc - for Chrome Live Extension Reloading Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clerc/dncedehofgbacgaojmingbdfogecjjbj)

I built Clerc for exactly this purpose. `npm run build` won't be enough though. You need to hook up a LiveReload compatible server to watch for file changes, and clerc will listen for the reload messages.

**Edit**: Oh sorry. I missed the part where you said "reloader is out of the question". I still think this is your best option though.